# How do I follow all threads in a particular channel?

Tags: slack

I'd like to not miss any posts in a particular channel, including those that are posted as part of threads. "All threads" shows me those I'm following, which is fine if I see the post or post in the thread. However, this doesn't show those threads that I miss, perhaps because they've been started on a fairly old post.

How do I follow all threads in a particular channel (preferably continually), or how do I make sure I see each posted message?

Comment: I would love this feature.  Could a Slack app be written to do this?